# Conditionals and past perfect continuous

Tags: past-tense, conditionals, perfect-aspect

I have a question about the third conditional and past perfect continuous.

The form of the third conditional is:

> If+past perfect,...... would+have+past participle

Is it possible to use past perfect **continuous** instead of past perfect?

For example:

- If I had been working for this company since 1996, I would have got a high salary.

Is this sentence right?

Comment: Yes, you can. But (1) you probably need a mixed conditional there, (2) you can't use *have got* to mean *have* after modal verbs. "If I had been working for this company since 1996, I would have a high salary."

Comment: Thank you so much for your remark Peter Shor, it's very interesting

Comment: @PeterShor Sorry, but the Brits do use: **would have got** where us Yanks would use **would have gotten** in the sense of receive. That seems kosher to me.

Comment: @Lambie: Yes, but is the sense he's trying to use *have got*-possession or *have got*-received? It seems to me like he probably was trying to use it to mean possession. My interpretation is that he's trying to say that if he had joined *then* he would have a high salary *now*.

Comment: @PeterShor Well, generally speaking, one receives a salary. What salary do you get? What salary do you receive? Anyway, for your idea, I'd say: would be getting. Cheers.